# Maven Projects not being recognized as a java project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am working on maven projects in eclipse but i am unable to refactor & do changes because i think it doesnot recognize as a java project because i keep getting error like "resource is not in the java build path of a java project"

I have tried all the things like

- searching for java build path by right clicking the project->properties. but there was no option for java build path
- i tried changing the installed jre(in windows->preference->java->build path->installed jre) & put the correct jdk but it doesnot work
- Also all the maven projects are building successfully in terminal.

so there is some problem with eclipse also all the pom.xml have some warning "Cannot read lifecycle mapping" & "Plugin Execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" I looked into their solution but it was of no help

- i have also tried changing my pom.xml according to the solutions for this lifecycle mapping problem but it didn't help
- initially i thought there is some issue with m2 eclipse but i also tried changing pom.xml acccordingly as well as going to windows-preferences-maven-discoveries-open catalog & installing m2e connector but there was some problem with the installation

Comment: your image is missing..

Comment: Try: Right click project -> Configure -> Convert to Maven project

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the maven goal eclipse:eclipse in your workspace location

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is in Kepler, try right clicking the project in mind -> Configure -> Convert to Maven Project